# I need to know what kind and size of brakes I need for my road bike/fixie

Tags: brakes, fixed-gear

I'm pretty sure it's a fixie but it's one speed and if I turn the rear wheel around it turns it into a fixie. I'm not aware of make and model but I bought a pair of brakes on Amazon that I thought were going to work. However, when it came to mounting it to the frame, where the screws go through the frame and connect to the brake didn't fit through my frame. I'm having a hard time finding the right hardware, and even am unsure how to search properly for the right type of hardware or brakes I would need to fit through my frame. I hope that's not confusing or anything I do not sure how to ask this question.

Comment: The lack of sentence structure makes it certainly more confusing than it needs to be, but without measurements or even photos it’s impossible to tell

Comment: Could you add either a photo of your bike, or a link to the bike model somewhere on the web ?  Also tell us what brakes you bought, with another link or a photo.

Comment: I'm going to take an initial crack at braking this up into smaller bites (sentences).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips on how to find the right brakes for your single speed or fixed gear road bike:

- Measure the inside width of your fork crown and chainstay where the brake mounts need to attach. This will determine what size brakes you need. Road bikes typically use short reach road caliper brakes.
- Inspect your existing brake mounts. Most road bikes have threaded mounting holes that accept a nut on the inside of the fork or chainstay. If yours are unthreaded, you may need adaptors.
- Consider the rim width and whether you need brakes suited for standard or wide rims. Measure your rim width to check.
- Make sure the brake arms have enough clearance for your tire size. Measure the diameter of your inflated tires.
- Look for road/track caliper brakes that are short reach and have adjustable springs/pads to accommodate different rim widths. Basic road calipers from brands like Tektro and Shimano are commonly used.
- For fixed gears, a front brake is recommended at minimum for safety stopping. Having both front and rear brakes is ideal.
- When ordering, pay close attention to the sizing specs for reach and mount style to ensure fit.
- Consult your local bike shop if unsure - they can help measure and recommend the proper brakes for your specific bike.

With some measurements and knowing your mounting style, you should be able to find appropriate braking options. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Good summary, but the forks and brake bridges that take the embedded nut are just countersunk, not threaded

Comment: "Having both front and rear brakes is ideal." and in several jurisdiction mandatory